# Export option not visible in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

When I generate my Highchart chart it generates complete. The only thing that doesn't show up is the export option.

Can anybody figure out what I am doing wrong?

Do I need to specify extra CSS styling options of some sort or include another JS script to allow this to work? I can't really figure it out at the moment.

```
chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    "chart": {
        "renderTo": "container",
        "type": "column"
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "Doorlooptijd exploten"
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "text": "Databron: Digibieb"
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "categories": {
            "2": "> xx",
            "1": "< xx",
            "0": "< xx"
        }
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "min": 0,
        "title": {
            "text": "Aantallen"
        }
    },
    "legend": {
        "layout": "vertical",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "align": "left",
        "verticalAlign": "top",
        "x": 100,
        "y": 100,
        "floating": 0,
        "shadow": 1
    },
    "exporting": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "column": {
            "pointPadding": 0.2,
            "borderWidth": 0
        }
    },
    "series": [{
        "name": "asd",
        "data": [1, 1, 1]
    }, {
        "name": "asd2",
        "data": [1, 1, 1]
    }, {
        "name": "asd3",
        "data": [1, 1, 1]
    }, {
        "name": "asd4",
        "data": [0, 0, 25]
    }, {
        "name": "asd5",
        "data": [54, 19, 53]
    }, {
        "name": "asd6",
        "data": [0, 0, 4]
    }, {
        "name": "asd8",
        "data": [22, 4, 28]
    }, {
        "name": "asd7",
        "data": [23, 40, 19]
    }, {
        "name": "asd9",
        "data": [23, 13, 8]
    }, {
        "name": "asd10",
        "data": [3, 0, 0]
    }]
});
```

Comment: You need to load the exporting.js script like this `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>` - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/).

Comment: @halfer, It's done.

Comment: Patrick, if you'd like to mark Core972's new answer as the correct solution, please do so.

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the exporting.js script like this after the main Highcharts script

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/)